# Program to create graph with modified bessel function

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, bessel-functions

$$e =\frac{1}{x}\frac{I_{1}(2x)}{I_{0}(2x)}$$
$$e =\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+x²\frac{8}{3}}}$$
$$e =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x\frac{4}{3}}} \frac{I_{\frac{2}{3}}(x\frac{4}{3}^{3/2})}{I_{\frac{-1}{3}}(x\frac{4}{3}^{3/2})}$$

I wanted to plot those functions but I'm having a hard time finding a program that does graphs with modified Bessel function of the first kind. Can anyone recommend me one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com) ? Just type `Plot[BesselI(1,2x)/BesselI(0,2x)/x,{x,-5,5}]`

into the dialog box, and press `Enter`. If you want to plot more than one function at once,

the syntax is `Plot[{... , ... , ...},{x, ... , ...}]`, where the dots are to be replaced

by the definitions of the functions, and the values of the horizontal plot limits.

Comment: I was able to plot everything that I needed: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[{[tanh%28x*sqrt2%29%2F%28x*sqrt2%29],+[BesselI%281,2x%29%2F%28x*BesselI%280,2x%29%29]+,[2%2F%281%2Bsqrt%281%2B%288%2F3%29*x%C2%B2%29%29],+[BesselI%282%2F3,x*%284%2F3%29^%283%2F2%29%29%2F%28x*sqrt%28%284%2F3%29%29*BesselI%28-1%2F3,x*%284%2F3%29^%283%2F2%29%29%29]},{x,+0,3}]


but I still don't think it's ideal for me so I'm still looking for a program capable of doing this.

Comment: @xsr: In that case, may I recommend *Mathematica* $($ the offline version of *Wolfram Alpha* $),$ or *Maple*.